# Javascript confirm is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one strange problem with javasctipt confirm method, whenever I call this, its throwing error like "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'confirm' of object [object Object] is not a function"

```
 var confirmVal = window.confirm("Please confirm?");
          if( confirmVal == true ){  

              return true;
          }
```

and my js files are in the html as like below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css">    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/jquery-ui.css">


<script src="js/vendor/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery-ui.js"></script> 


<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/star-rating.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/toastr.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script> 
<script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/star-rating.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/toastr.min.js"></script>
```

Strange is, in my other html file its working fine..
Please help me, what am I doing wrong here..

Comment: where were you calling the function during the document.ready or in custom function ?

Comment: in custom function only.. I am assuring document got ready

Comment: have you tried it without `window.`?

Comment: yes I have tried without window also, its same error

Comment: Which browser you are working in? Try different browsers if working in other then probably it's something with your browser

Answer (score 2):

The code is correct except for the ***return*** statement which must be in a function.

```
function confirmation(){
  var confirmVal = window.confirm("Please confirm?");
      if( confirmVal == true ){  
          return true;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Code is correct only, its working in my other html page.. But in this page something went wrong with js files..

Answer (score 0):

```
navigator.notification.confirm(
    'ARE YOU SURE!', // message
     myCallBck,            // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
    'CONFIRM',           // title
    ['CONFIRM','CANCEL']     // buttonLabels
);

function myCallBck(index){
   console.log(index);
}
```

Comment: Iceman, yes same code is working in my other html file also.. but here its not working..

Comment: You are overwriting window somewhere in those js files!!

Comment: do something remove all js inclusions and try if it works and add each js file one by one.

Comment: Ok but how do I check this "overwriting window somewhere in those js files!!"

Comment: comment each js inclusion off and check if it works.. sorry no other easy way out.

Comment: Ok sir, I will check

Comment: probably you are calling the confirm inside a function in which case return is valid, but your snippet is not showing the function above. thats y every1 is pointing it out as a syntax error.

Comment: I am calling it on deviceready function only, I have tried with removing all the js files then also same problem :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118173/discussion-between-iceman-and-mallikarjun-hampannavar).

Answer (score 0):

You are using return statement but who's taking care of that statement if you want to use return statement you need to wrap your code into function

```
var confirmed = confirm("yes or cancel");

function confirmMe (){
     if (confirmed){
          return true;
     }
 }
```

you can also do this way

```
function confirmMe (){
     return confirmed;
}
```

//going to return true or false

You can check if you are not overriding window object. Open console and type window and you can see if window has the confirm method.

Answer (score -2):

Remove "return true" as it is must be wrapped inside a function
Learn more about [return here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

```js
var confirmVal = window.confirm("Please confirm?");
          if( confirmVal == true ){  
            alert("alright");             
          }
```

Comment: error with confirm method.. Anyway I have checked by removing return true then also same problem..